# R install pacakages error (escape in character string) in Library Path

Tags: r, debugging, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging

I have tried editing the output of `.libpaths()` and changing it but i am still getting the following errors below,

```
PS C:\Users\Jesus> radian
Error: '\D' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'D:\D"
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie"
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32 (64-bit)
```

if you notice  the `'\D' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'D:\D"` is apparent even when I switch into radian.

```
r$> .libPaths()
[1] "D:/Documents/R/win-library/4.1"     "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library"
```

```
r$> remotes::install_github("ManuelHentschel/vscDebugger")
Downloading GitHub repo ManuelHentschel/vscDebugger@HEAD
v  checking for file 'C:\Users\Jesus\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSaUPCL\remotes27fc9487e46\ManuelHentschel-vscDebugger-ce8f248/DESCRIPTION'
-  preparing 'vscDebugger': (359ms)
v  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  cleaning src
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
   Omitted 'LazyData' from DESCRIPTION
-  building 'vscDebugger_0.4.7.tar.gz'
   
Installing package into 'D:/Documents/R/win-library/4.1'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Error: '\D' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'D:\D"
Execution halted
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package 'C:/Users/Jesus/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpSaUPCL/file27fc7270a15/vscDebugger_0.4.7.tar.gz' had non-zero exit status
```

I get this error `Error: '\D' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'D:\D"`
I think it only happens on specific packages I try to install too.

If anyone knows how to solve this, so I can R debugging on VSCode.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I figure out it was something wrong with my `.Rprofile`
looking at other forums it looks like deleting your `.Rdata` file helps too.

it generated as

```
# LanguageServer Setup Start (do not change this chunk)
# to remove this, run languageserversetup::remove_from_rprofile
if (requireNamespace('languageserversetup', quietly = TRUE)) {
  options(langserver_library = 'D:\Documents/languageserver-library')
  languageserversetup::languageserver_startup()
  unloadNamespace('languageserversetup')
}
# LanguageServer Setup End
```

and the fix is changing the `\` in `'D:\Documents/languageserver-library'` to `/`

as such `'D:/Documents/languageserver-library'`

cheers